# Wicket 6 - Feedback message not showing until request after the request in which it happened

Tags: wicket, wicket-6

I have an AjaxButton. The event fires, and I'm testing a scenario where I need to add a feedback and return without committing the change. I add the feedback at the page level (our feedback only shows page level messages...others are showing on component level feedback panels).  I add the WebMarkupContainer that contains the feedback panel to the target.  This exact thing works on every other button on the page.

But for this button, which happens to be the only one where defaultformprocessing is not false, the feedback doesn't show.  To the user's view, nothing happens except our processing veil appears and then disappears. If I hit submit again, THEN the message and feedback are shown. I stuck a timestamp on it to see if it was showing the one from the 2nd request or the 1st.  It's from the 1st.

What's more, a breakpoint in the feedback's filter shows that the filter was never called in the 1st request, but is called BEFORE the event processing on the 2nd request.  It accepts the message as intended.

I set defaultformprocessing to FALSE on this button as a test, and in fact, messages suddenly work.  But of course, that also means the form doesn't get processed. Can someone help me square this circle?

AjaxButton:

```
add(new AjaxButton("btnCreateRequest", getForm()) {
        @Override
        public void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
           //stuff happens
           target.add(getFeedbackPanelForAjax());
           String date = new Date().toGMTString();
           System.out.println("ADDING MESSAGE - " + date);
           getPage().error("This is a message! " + date);
           return;               
        }
        
        @Override
        public void onError(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
            getPage().error("There was an error processing your request");
            target.add(getFeedbackPanelForAjax());
            target.add(form);
        }
    }.setVisible(enabled));
```

UPDATE:
getFeedbackPanelForAjax returns the web markup container that the feedback resides in.  I've also tried adding the feedback directly to the target.

```
public Component getFeedbackPanelForAjax() {
    return (Component) getForm().get("feedbackWmc");
}
```

Where the feedback is added:

```
    feedback = new FRFeedbackPanel("feedback") {
        @Override
        public boolean isVisible() {
            if(anyMessage()){
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    };
    // feedback container
    WebMarkupContainer feedbackWmc = new WebMarkupContainer("feedbackWmc");
    getForm().add(feedbackWmc.setOutputMarkupId(true).setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true));
    feedbackWmc.add(feedback.setOutputMarkupId(true).setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true));
```

I can say that through debugging, I put a breakpoint in anyMessage() and it returns false in this case at the same time that getPage().getFeedbackMessages() returns the message correctly. I commented out this override of isVisible() and indeed, the message shows. The problem is, that it means the artifacts of the feedback panel show when there are no messages as well, which is not what we want.

This anyMessage() solution works perfectly when I'm in an event that is defaultformprocessing=false. I suppose I could do an anyMessage() || getPage().getFeedbackMessages(), but my understanding was that anyMessage was supposed to find if there was ANY message in the hierarchy for this panel. Is that not so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you cannot replicate the problem in a small quickstart?

One idea: I've seen similar problems when the FeedbackPanel collects its messages too early, i.e. before you add the error to the page.
FeedbackMessagesModel keeps the messages to render until the end of the request - maybe some of your code triggers this by accessing the messages model.

Comment: Would adding the feedback to the target BEFORE the message is issued possibly cause that?  There's very little code above where the message is added.  I have generally not had luck with quickstarts ever replicating a complex problem.

Comment: Show us the body of `getFeedbackPanelForAjax()` method.

Comment: @martin-g See body of post for update.  I've discovered some additional things along the way.

Comment: @Entropy override onConfigure() and call setVisible() instead.

Comment: That was it exactly.  Once I changed to use onConfigure, most of the wackyness stopped.  Thanks.